# What to select as boot device when installing dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, server, system-installation

I have a server that runs Ubuntu 14.04 and contains some custom configuration that I do not want to change. I would like to install a dual boot on this server so that I could use an up to date version of Ubuntu and still have an option to switch back to the old system if needed. The machine uses two virtual disks (sda and sdb) with partitions setup like so:

- sda has Ubuntu 14.04 installation and acts as the boot device, also contains separate partition for /home
- sdb has a partition for old data which I cannot delete and then 5 partitions which I created manually for the second OS (/, /swap, /tmp, /var, /home)

During the installation process, when I try to manually configure storage device, I am asked to select a boot device for the second OS. My system uses BIOS. Does that mean I need to create one more partition on sdb? And will there be a problem that this parittion is not at the beginning of a disk and the partitions are specified with a GPT partition table?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS. Both on same drive? UEFI uses ESP - efi system partition for boot files. BIOS uses MBR or very first sector of a drive for first part of boot files. If both are Ubuntu, you only will have one Ubuntu entry and one initial grub. But that grub menu should then offer to boot other installs. If UEFI create only one ESP per drive/device. If BIOS you only have one MBR per drive. Last install will be default boot. But major update to first install, may change it to default. You just have to manage that.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to AskUbuntu!
just some advice to get good answers. As you see from the first comment its hard to understand your situation from your description. It helps if you write more about your actual setup. You might want to edit your question and add more information, including things mentioned in the comments. For example it might help to show the output of "lsblk" to see what drives and partitions you have. Or write where exactly your are asked to make that selection.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I will edit my post accordingly